# UIPageViewController on UINavigationController does not relayout its child viewcontroller since changing orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

I am making the following view controller(VC) structure.

[UINavigationViewController] -> [UIPageViewController] -> [UIViewControllers]

then, this VC should support portrait and landscape orientation.

A problem I have is raised at changing orientation to any sides.

[image]

you can see the problem.
[image]

***red area*** is background color of child VC on UIPageViewController.
***blue area*** is background color of UIPageViewController.

I guess child VC was not relayouted by UIPageViewController. I have figured it out for a long time. I finally ended up finding a work around to add the following overridden function to **custom** UIPageViewController.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self setViewControllers:self.viewControllers
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO
                  completion:NULL];
}
```

Although moving a view to downside is showed as soon as finishing rotation. This code solves the problem roughly.

anyway, **I really want to know any nice and natural solutions.**

**UPDATE**
My app works well on iOS6. it may be iOS7 bug?

Comment: you made 2 different xib for different orientation?

Comment: I ran into layout issues when I used a page view controller outside of a parent view controller (as you are doing). Those issues disappeared when I added the page view controller to a parent view controller. I used the boilerplate code from Apple's Page-Based Application Xcode template.

Comment: @MirkoCatalano No. custom UIPageViewController is created programmatically, but UINavigationController is rootViewController of the app. I use a storyboard for building UI. The reason that I didn't use a storyboard for UIPageViewController is to interact with a button which is on a custom UITableViewCell. I didn't use a storyboard to make the button since the button is dynamically created on runtime.

Comment: your problem is the 20px for the bar

Comment: When UIViewController presents UIPageViewController, it works well. But, when UIPageViewController is pushed to UINavigationController, it works a little strange.

Comment: @MirkoCatalano How can I solve it? I haven't found any solution out..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have solved this problem to place the following SINGLE line of code in [viewDidLoaded] of custom UIPageViewController.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

I supposed that UIPageViewController has a scroll view, and if it is embedded in UINavigationController, it will lay out incorrectly since changing orientation.

Fortunately, my solution fitted in the problem.

@MirkoCatalano Thank you for your comments. these are very helpful to found out right solution.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me. I was stuck on this for three days. I wish I can give you more upvotes.

Comment: @Greeso That's my pleasure. I had also suffered from that issue during the time you spent. I'm really happy as you are.